# MVC view does not see reference to other project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a solution with two projects in it.  One is a console app and the other is an ASP.NET MVC app.

My console app is using entity framework and I want to access some of its data from the ASP.NET MVC app.

I added a reference to my console app project in the asp.net app project and in the controller this works fine, I am able to access the database context and see the data.

However, the view throws the standard "The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" exception.

Why can the controller see the Console apps namespace but the view cannot?

Do I need to add another reference somewhere?

Edit:

This is what using statement looks like:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList < PlacesAPI.Models.RootDomain>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
```

I have tried not fully qualifying and doing `@using PlacesAPI` but it always fails to find reference to `PlacesAPI` but it works fine in controller.

Edit:

I found a comment on another thread that said if you are using an external refernece from a virtual source like a database (which I am) then you have to put a reference in the root web.config file not the views web.config file.

I tried adding:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
```

and

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="PlacesAPI" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

to the root web.config but it gives same error.

Comment: You need a using statement in your cshtml file.

Comment: I have the using statement but it throw an exception  "The type or namespace name could not be found"

Comment: Is it fully qualified? Also, you may want to add the namespace to the pages::namespaces element in Views\web.config

Comment: I updated question with the top of view.  I added it to web.config and no change

Comment: It now throws the error in the web.config file.  It cant see it but in controller it can.  I dont understand why

Comment: Isn't your namespace PlacesAPI.Models?

Comment: Same thing with Places.Models.  It says `The type or namespace name 'PlacesAPI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: What's the namespace for your controller?

Comment: The namespace def you add to Views\web.config must be fully qualified, e.g. PagedList.Mvc.PlacesAPI or whatever it happens to be. That is what allows you to simply reference PlacesAPI in the '@model' declaration in the cshtml file

Comment: Have you added dll of other project in main project?

Comment: Yeah I had but I hadn't added assembly reference properly in web.config. I only added the namespace reference. Once I added assembly reference as per my answer it worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

Problem was I was adding a namespace reference but not the reference to the assembly in the views web.config.  I also needed to add:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
      <add assembly="PlacesAPI" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: after 2 hours looking for a solution for the error "BC30002: Type OtherProject.SomeClass is not defined",  finally I solved it by adding the assembly "OtherProject"...